# AWS EC2 : upgrade from AMI 1 to AMI 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade, amazon-ami

Is-there an easy way to upgrade from Amazon Linux AMI to Amazon Linux 2 AMI, or do I have to create a new instance and do again all my server setup ?

Thanks for your feedback,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no easy way. You have to create a new Linux 2 instance.

From: [Amazon Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html)

> If you are currently using the Amazon Linux AMI, we recommend that you
>   migrate to Amazon Linux 2. To migrate to Amazon Linux 2, launch an
>   instance or create a virtual machine using the current image. Install
>   your application on Amazon Linux 2, plus any packages required by your
>   application. Test your application, and make any changes required for
>   it to run on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Hi,

ok so if I understand well, this is a completely manual process ? :)

Thanks fro your quick feedback anyway!

Comment: @Logboo unfortunately yes.

Comment: AWS offers a https://github.com/amazonlinux/upgrade-modules that is good for nothing.